# how to implement console command ping - a 10.10.10.1 in C#

Tags: c#, ping

I am able to implement ping using C# (to check whether a machine is available).

But I am not able to get the equivalent of console command ping [-a] targetipaddress which also resolves the address to hostname.

This I require to use in case of  non domain scenarios (such as a workgroup).

Example : (a) using ping from command console ping 10.10.10.1
(b) ping -a 10.10.10.1

Code I am using for (a)

```
    static string pingmachine(string ipaddress)
    {

        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingReply pingresult = ping.Send(ipaddress);
        return pingresult.Status.ToString();

    }
```

Please help me to do the equivalent of example (b). Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code for your simple ping and tell us what needs to change.

Comment: static string pingmachine(string ipaddress)
        {

            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingresult = ping.Send(ipaddress);
            return pingresult.Status.ToString();
            
        }

Comment: Please edit your question to include your simple ping **and tell us what needs to change.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward.

From msdn:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingTest
{
    public class PingExample
    {
        // args[0] can be an IPaddress or host name.
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions ();

            // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
            // but change the fragmentation behavior.
            options.DontFragment = true;

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (data);
            int timeout = 120;
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (args[0], timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                IPAddress ip;
                if(IPAddress.TryParse(args[0],out ip))
                {
                    var host =  System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
                    Console.WriteLine("Host {0}",host.HostName);
                }
                Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
                Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
                Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
                Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
                Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. However, I am not able to understand which part of it resolves the hostname (which is what we get when using the -a with the ping command in the console).

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks a ton!